# How to list Databricks scopes using Python when working on it secret API

Tags: python-3.x, databricks

I can create a scope. However, I want to be sure to create the scope only when it does not already exist. Also, I want to do the checking using Python? Is that doable?

What I have found out is that I can create the scope multiple times and not get an error message -- is this the right way to handle this? The document https://docs.databricks.com/security/secrets/secret-scopes.html#secret-scopes points out using

```
databricks secrets list-scopes
```

to list the scopes. However, I created a cell and ran

```
%sh
databricks secrets list-scopes
```

I got an error message saying "/bin/bash: databricks: command not found".

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This will list all the scopes.

```
dbutils.secrets.listScopes()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't run the CLI commands from your databricks cluster (through a notebook). CLI needs to be installed and configured on your own workstation and then you can run these commands on your workstation after you configure connecting to a databricks worksapce using the generated token.

Answer (score 0):

still you can run databricks cli command in notebook by same kind `databricks-cli`setup in cluster level and run as `bash` command . install databricks cli by `pip install databricks-cli`